# Sort an object of arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

with an object like

```
{
 5: ['C','A','B'],
 8: ['E','F','D']
}
```

I'm trying to sort the arrays of each key, while returning the entire object. The above would come back looking like this:

```
{
 5: ['A','B','C'],
 8: ['D','E','F']
}
```

I've tried lots of variations of

```js
Object.keys(myObj).map(k => { 
   return { k: myObj[k].sort() };
}
```

But this puts a literal `k` as each key instead of maintaining the keys from the original object. Not to mention this also creates an array of objects since `map` is returning an object for each key.

*Edit:*

*I've found lots of "sort array of objects" - but not a "sort object of arrays" on SO - dupe and link if it already exists please.*

Comment: do `return { [k]: myObj[k].sort() };`

Comment: Thank you, that does solve the literal `k` issue. However the result of the `map` above is an array of objects, instead of an object of arrays (I realize that's how `map` works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const data = {
 5: ['C','A','B'],
 8: ['E','F','D']
}

let dataSort = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item] = data[item].sort()  
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(dataSort)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try.

```
 const newSortedObj = Object.entries(yourObject).reduce((acc, [key, values]) => {
    acc[key] = values.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));

    return acc;
  }, {})
```

Do consider the locale and the character casing when you do `string sort`. Have a look [at the local compare API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)